# Building a database from a time series

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

So, I have the following problem:

I'm doing some time series analysis and I have a model with something like 10^7 identities, or ids (for instance each mobile phone on a country).

Each Id has associated events (for instance days), which can span to at most 10^4 events. For each  event and identity, there are different "attributes" (for instance the number of messages sent by the phone X on that day Y).

I'm trying to design a mysql db for handling such amount of information. I will be primary interested in doing queries for time distributions (e.g. number of messages on that particular day; or number of active phones between day X and Y).

1. My first though was using a table for each different value: on each table the row is an identity, and each column there is a day. If there are N different attributes, then I would have N different tables. This poses the problem of having 10^4 columns on each table; I'm not sure it is a good/standard/efficient practice.
2. My second though was to have one single table with 10^7*10^4 rows (a so called many to many relationship): the first column has a primary key, the second one the identity's id, the third the event's day, and the next columns the associated attributes of that identity on that particular day.

I asking what's your advice: "for historical reasons" I already have a non-mysql database created (with lots and lots of .txt files) and before trying to migrate it, I want to know if it is really worth it. As you might understand, currently a query in my *.txt database can be as expensive as it can get: I have to typically open each and every .txt do to a query. This translates in something like 10-30m for each query. So any suggestion below that limit can actually be very useful to my problem.

Thank you for your time,
Jorge

Comment: It sounds to me like you are trying to build OLAP cube manually. Sorry, I'm not familiar with the tools Mysql gives for OLAP, but I'm pretty sure it should be something on the market.

Comment: Could be achieved without using OLAP. It looks like a straightforward event recording system, with a large "event" table with event time, device ID, event type and other attributes. If the different events have different metadata then you'd need a table for each event type hooked into the main event table. Importantly, a "many to many relationship is _not_ a single table, but (at least) three, to avoid the vast numbers you suggest.

Comment: Yeah, this manytomany would be simpler because each identity only has a "id", no more info, and the same for the timestamp. But thanks, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store a rather cmoplex matrix of information in a relational database.  Here are a couple of questions you need to answer before even starting:

- Is there missing data on any given day?  That is, could id=x have a real value for item=y, but that value is missing from the database for some operational reason.
- Do most or all of the items have values on any given day for a given id?  That is, are you delaing with a sparse matrix problem or not?

Storing the items in separate columns is a non-starter.  MySQL has a hard limit of 4,096 columns per row (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html)), which is less than 10^4.

It would seem that the more normalized approach is feasible, although each row requires the id and item id and the values need to be type-consistent.  If you are storing numbers, no problem.  If some are better stored as integers, others as monetary values, and others as strings, then you might have a challenge.

I suspect that a hybrid approach might work.  You might have some items that are frequently used that could be stored in a single table.  Many more items would be stored using the normalized approach.  You can then consider partitioning strategies to optimize access.

You haven't provided enough detail to devise such a strategy.  Often, the approach is to partition the data by time.  In this case, though, it might be better to partition the data by item, so all values can be fetched within a partition.

Comment: Ok, thanks, nice answer. So, yes, there could be items with missing data on a given day and yes, most items have values for a given day (and yes, all integers). What I ask is if by any chance quering a mysql like that can reach the time scale of my current one, e.g. 10-30m (with the 10^7 10^4 entries) if a priori it doesn't seem so, then it doesn't even worth to try.

Comment: The answer to that question depends on your hardware, on the engine used for accessing the data, and on physical data structure.  I think you should ask the question on the DB forum, more like "how can I get this to work with MySQL".